# Speech recognition library is giving error of input device

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, speech-recognition

I am doing voice recognition using python library "Speech Recognition",Every thing is going well with audio files but when i use mike, it is showing this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StoTUsingMike.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/home/nash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

I have seen 2 or 3 more posts regarding this error on stack overflow but there is no clear solution.
Kindly help me out of this problem.

Comment: if a mic is actually plugged, did you try with `sr.Microphone(device_index=INSERT_YOUR_DEVICE_INDEX_HERE)` ? check this thread https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/269

Comment: Sir how i can get the device index in ubuntu 16.04? I searched but didn't find.

Comment: check this answer https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/269#issuecomment-328154742

Comment: Sir i have gone through all these stuff. But didn't find any solution.. This script return nothing.